# Soyuz for Sale?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, soyuz-spacecraft, russia

Reading through some stuff on the interwebs I came across some information saying that some old Soyuz Capsules are keep in a junkyard. Does anyone know if it's actually possible to purchase one of these old space capsules?

Comment: One wonders if, even if you can, there's anything good in it.

Comment: Nah, it would just go into either my room or backyard to likely become an immersive KSP Console.

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  There are already answers for this question in https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21392/26446 and https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18092/26446

Answer (score 12):

The descent vehicles of the Soyuz spacecraft are approximately half reusable. The most expensive structural elements are reused. Therefore, the cost of a used descent vehicle is high.  However, sometimes these descent vehicles are sold.
Recently:
Technik Museum Speyer in 2010 acquired Soyuz TM-19.

CITE DE L'ESPACE in Toulouse, France in 2017 tried to acquire Soyuz MS-03. Probably unsuccessful.

Science Museum, London in 2017 acquired Soyuz TMA-19M.

Some  descent vehicles had a very complicated history and can be found in unexpected places. In any case, the cost of acquiring them will not be cheap.

P.S. Компания «Главкосмос» выставила на публичную продажу оригинал спускаемого аппарата космического корабля «Союз МС-08». Цена аппарата публично не озвучивается, поскольку является предметом коммерческих переговоров. До этого предприятие не продавало капсулы.

The company "Glavkosmos" has put up for public sale the original of the descent vehicle of the Soyuz MS-08 spacecraft. The price of the device is not publicly announced, since it is the subject of commercial negotiations. Before that, the company did not sell the descent vehicle.
https://www.trade.glavkosmos.com/news/3345/

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks for the info!

Comment: Is either of the museums mentioned the site of the Soyuz descent module and VA capsule in the image?

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean This is a photo as an example "very complicated history and unexpected places". It is unknown how these three capsules (one more on the left - something like Vostok) got to this place and where these capsules are now. The likely version of the story of their origin is these capsules from the disbanded Ukrainian military school or institute. The internal design of the VA capsule differs from other models. Perhaps this is a VA prototype. In EXIF: Date taken: 2010:11:24 12:09:59. At this time, the capsules were in tracking facility of State Space Agency of Ukraine in Crimea.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a lot of Space legacy left behind and many used systems are not properly preserved in Russia and other CIS countries, I think through the right channels one might be able to acquire it. Complications could arise if the nation which would be purchasing might not yet possess the technology as well as any other political barricades.

Also if one is planning to acquire such a system for exhibition purposes, make your mind as it would be very difficult and would have a lot of bureaucratic procedure in the middle. The proposed systems should also be sufficiently old and not in use / planned for any future operations( this includes the materials, manufacturing methods, study purpose and etc.)

Many Russian museums and universities have their own used space systems and components which were either gifted by the industry or lobbied through their alumni.

Honestly, most of these space capsules are burnt and charcoal in colour, it is better to request them to build a mock model for exhibition purposes.

PS: I am a student in Russia .))

Comment: Thanks! I honestly would have figured that since there were lot of the capsules that went to space and back that they would be able to be purchased by private collectors. The images of the capsules in a junkyard-type place kind of proved the idea in my head.